# Can cold start happen multiple times per invocation in Firebase functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to organize my functions with some business logic and some helper functions that are running only from within my code (not exposed endpoints).

As I am trying to organize it, some helper functions would depend on admin or other imports, so in both `business.js` and `common.js` I would have

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
```

Lets say `business.js` function calls some function from `common.js`, and they both use `admin.firestore()` - how does cold start work in this case? Would both of these functions pay for the cold start time - would `common.childCalledFunction` pay for cold start even if admin is initialized for called function `business.parentCalledFunction`? Is cold start once per invocation or per each function? If per function, what would be preferred solution to common functions like fetch and validate from Firestore?

I have found many articles online about cold start but never actually answer to this particular case, or maybe I just misread it.
Also, my knowledge of javascript is limited.

Answer (score 3):

See note at end.

When using `require()`, you pay the cold start cost of loading the code whenever `require()` is first used for a particular library which involves fetching the code (and its dependencies) from the disk and evaluating it. Further to this, there is another cold start when you call the initialization method of these libraries.

The Firebase SDKs use the named singleton pattern. When you first invoke
`initializeApp(name)` (where `name` defaults to `"[DEFAULT]"` when omitted) you initialize an instance of the SDK's core functionality for that name. Care must be taken around `initializeApp(name)` as you can only initialize each named app once without it throwing a "App named X already exists" error. Additionally each component of the Firebase SDK gets initialized the first time you call it for a given app using `getFirestore(app)` or `firestore(app)` (where `app` defaults to the default app when omitted) in the case of Firestore. Unlike `initializeApp()` these "get component" initializers can be called as many times as you want.

So in your case, calling `initializeApp()` at the top of both `common.js` and `business.js` would actually crash your application. Instead, you should move the `initializeApp()` into it's own `firebase.js` file so it is only evaluated once, but can be used in multiple places.

This would mean swapping out these lines:

```
// business.js / common.js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
```

to:

```
// business.js / common.js
const admin = require('./firebase.js')
```

```
// firebase.js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
module.exports = admin;
```

```
project/
  functions/
    lib/
      business.js
      common.js
      firebase.js
    functions/
      feat1.js
      feat2.js
    index.js
    ...
  ...
```

As you are new to JavaScript, take the time to learn the new versions of the JavaScript SDKs, known as the *Modular SDKs*, as these are what will be using going forward in new versions of Firebase. This will require using a compiler step on your code before production, but it does offer the ability to trim off the fat components of the SDK you aren't actually using. It also involves learning the new names for functions such as `getFirestore()` instead of `admin.firestore()` and using `doc(firestore, path)` instead of `firestore.doc(path)`. You should also use ES6 module imports instead of `require()`.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, detailed explanation and examples. It clarifies few things for me, but still got some question marks above my head.. If I understood correctly, paying for cold start would happen only for first 'require' (in business.js when business.parentCalledFunction)? Let's assume there is no explicit 'admin.initializeApp()', rather 'require("firebase-functions")'?

Comment: @DorianPavetić For the example you gave, that is one of the two types of "cold start" you will experience and you are right in that it happens for the first require - any further calls to require will return the same result as the first. However, don't just disregard the other "cold start" type of creating an instance where handshaking authentication & networking needs to take place.